# Geocoder rails filter nearbys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

Just wondering how I might filter the results of a controller when finding nearby 'clients' in my case

I have this on my show page

```
    <% for client in @due.nearbys(15) %>
            <tr><td><b><%= link_to client.name, client %> <%= link_to client.surname, client %>:</b>
              <%= link_to client.scheduled_date.strftime('%A %m-%d-%y'), client %>
```

On my clients_controller I specified

```
@due =  current_user.clients.where(['scheduled_date < ?', 6.months.ago]).order('scheduled_date DESC')
```

However I get

```
undefined method `nearbys' for #<Client::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x00007fb2a2aea67>
```

not sure how to call the clients nearbys whcih does work normally but to add the filter, should I add it as a scope? thanks!

Comment: Do you add `extend Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord` to Client model?

Comment: Thanks @Quân Hoàng how do I do this? And how to filter the results thanks !!!

Comment: To use Geocoder gem, you have to add `geocoded_by :your_address_column` to the Model. or add `extend Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord` to Model if you are not using Rails.
Following: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#use-outside-of-rails

Comment: Yes installed and populating last long etc however if I want to filter my clients by a scheduled date I can’t seem to work out the logic so that not all clients show up

Comment: I've added the gem and it works to geocode my results and map is fine. I would like to filter the nearby's on a show page to show clients who are nearby only when they haven't been serviced for a few months. How do I do this? currently all nearby clients are showing

Comment: It's depending on your logic. but for get nearbys
```

Client.near([this_client.lng, this_client.lat], 50, units: :km).where('actived_at', '<=', 3.months.ago)
```
Something like above code. the where conditions is depend on your business.

Update: I moved the this comment to Answer to use code block.

Answer (score 1):

It's depending on your logic. but for get nearbys

```
Client.near([this_client.lng, this_client.lat], 50, units: :km).where('actived_at', '<=', 3.months.ago)
```

Something like above code. the where conditions is depend on your business.

Comment: yes. it's can be place at controller. (or you can define a function on Client model, Like get_nearby_unactive_clients). then call it everywhere you want.

Comment: Oh thanks Quân. Final question. Would that be as a scope?

Comment: @EvanRoberts Yes. of course. it's good. 
btw, Thank for type my name correctly. ^^!

Comment: thanks Quân I wish people got my name right and didn't add an s! haha thanks again